# Stacking patches on the Empress Zoia guitar pedal

Tags: guitar-effects, synthesizer, effects-pedal

The [Empress Zoia](https://empresseffects.com/products/zoia) guitar pedal looks way cool for my uses: a modular synth with a huge amount of flexibility.

I would be looking at using the Zoia together with the [Origin Effects Revival Drive](https://origineffects.com/product/revivaldrive-compact/) to replace the big pedal board I currently use on tour.

But how do you stack effects (looping, modulation, reverb, etc)?  Do you have to program each stack from scratch or is there a way of copying and pasting different patches into different portions of the signal path?